# Difference in output when for pytorch NN on batch and individual forward pass

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I have the following program:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.net = nn.Sequential()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, 32)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(32, 32)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(32, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

net = Net(input_size=10, output_size=1)
x = torch.from_numpy(np.random.rand(2,10)).type(torch.FloatTensor)

y = net(x)
x0 = x[0,]
y0 = net(x0)

print(y[0,],y0)

assert y0.item() == y[0,].item(), "Outputs not equal"
```

In the program even after giving the same inputs once in batch and once without batch, why does the NN return two different outputs? Although the difference is very small, but I was curious as to why this happens?

I was expecting the output to be exactly the same as all the computations are deterministic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key reason for these variations is the finite precision of **floating-point arithmetic** in computer systems. While neural networks are theoretically deterministic, these numerical approximations can lead to tiny discrepancies.

Pytorch numerical accuracy: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/numerical_accuracy.html